# Voucher code affects the prices of products shown in EMail and PDF

Tags: email, discount, pdf

I have a weird problem. I am applying the voucher discount on the cart for newsletter subscribers and it works on Checkout process without a problem. But in the email and pdf files I see the prices for products are changed unlogicly.

I have attached an image to show the difference.
Left side is on PDF and EMail and right side is on Admin Panel.

[image: Inconsistency between PDF/EMail and Admin Panel]

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow the discount was spreaded on products seperatly and that was the reason of the weird prices. I checked the PDF creation code and found out that it was substructing the amounf from product price, I changed it to use the real product price. Now the problem is gone.